# Python - Tkinter: How can I create multiple radiobuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobuttonlist

Me again. :p
I've define RadioButtons in a group to reduce my code. But how could I create multiple radioButtons in this way? For example I want to create two lists but in both I want only choice one choice.
Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)#Wahl inizialisieren
scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

master.geometry('1000x500') #Abmessung Fenster
master.title('test') #Tittel Fenster


def create_window(): #Definion und Festlegung neues Fenster
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title('result')
    toplevel.geometry('1500x1000')
    toplevel.focus_set()

   sex = [
    ("male",1),
    ("female",2),
    ("male1",3),
    ("female1",4),
]

test = [
    ("test",5),
    ("test1",6),
    ("test2",7),
    ("test3",8),
]

def ShowChoice():
    print var.get()

#Erzeugung
Checkliste----------------------------------------------------------------

Label(master,
      text='''choose one answer:''',
      padx = 20).pack()

for txt, val in sex:
    Radiobutton(master,
                text=txt,
                justify = LEFT,
                padx = 20,
                variable=var,
                variable=v,
                command=ShowChoice,
                value=val).pack(anchor=N)

Label(master,
      text='''choose one answer:''',
      padx = 20).pack()

for txt, val in test:
    Radiobutton(master,
                text=txt,
                justify = LEFT,
                padx = 20,
                variable=var,
                variable=v1,
                command=ShowChoice,
                value=val).pack(anchor=N)



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Button(master, text='forward', command=create_window).pack(padx=5, 
anchor=N, pady=4)


master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give each Radiobutton group its own `variable`. But then how does `ShowChoice` know what `variable` to call `.get()` on? Well, one way to handle that is to make the `command` callback function a lambda that has the `variable` as a default argument. And while we're doing that we might as well pass the `txt` as a default arg too.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

sex = [
    ("male", 1),
    ("female", 2),
    ("male1", 3),
    ("female1", 4),
]

test = [
    ("test", 5),
    ("test1", 6),
    ("test2", 7),
    ("test3", 8),
]

def ShowChoice(text, v):
    print(text, v.get())

varsex = tk.IntVar()
varsex.set(sex[0][1])

tk.Label(master, text='Choose one answer:').pack()

for txt, val in sex:
    tk.Radiobutton(master, text=txt, variable=varsex, value=val,
        command=lambda t=txt, v=varsex: ShowChoice(t, v)).pack(anchor=tk.N)

vartest = tk.IntVar()
vartest.set(test[0][1])

tk.Label(master, text='Choose one answer:').pack()

for txt, val in test:
    tk.Radiobutton(master, text=txt, variable=vartest, value=val,
        command=lambda t=txt, v=vartest: ShowChoice(t, v)).pack(anchor=tk.N)

master.mainloop()
```

I have edited out various things in your program that aren't relevant to your problem. It's a Good Idea to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on the actual program, rather than bloating your question code with irrelevant stuff.

I've converted your `print` statement to a `print` function call to make it easier to run your program on Python 3, all you need to do is change `Tkinter` to `tkinter` in the `import` statement.

---

I also got rid of that "star" import. Sure, plenty of Tkinter examples use "star" import, but it's not recommended: it pollutes your namespace with over 170 names in Python 2 (and around 130 names in Python 3), which is messy and can lead to name collisions. And although there's a little more typing when you do `import Tkinter as tk` it makes the code easier to read because it's obvious which names are Tkinter names.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you. :) Ps.: If I will post a code again, I will notice this! I am new and I haven't experience yet.

Comment: Forgotten - sorry. ^^